# Replace each occurrence of word that starts with # from a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Replace words or strings that starts with # from a file.

For example here is the file with following lines:

```
$ cat file.txt
#apple sd#kf #banana adfe
#apple we#re #banana cow
```

here is the expected output

```
$ cat output.txt 
fruit=apple sd#kf fruit=banana adfe
fruit=apple we#re fruit=banana cow
```

when I use following

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i~/^#/ && $i="fruit="$i }1'
```

I get following output:

```
fruit=#apple sd#kf fruit=#banana adfe
fruit=#apple we#re fruit=#banana cow
```

when I use following

```
sed 's/^#/fruit=/g'
```

I get

```
fruit=apple sd#kf #banana adfe
fruit=apple we#re #banana cow
```

How do I get expected result using awk, sed, grep?

Answer (score 5):

The `^` asserts the start of the string, that is why you only see a single replacement.

You might replace the `^` by `\B` to assert a non word boundary.

```
sed -E 's/\B#/fruit=/g' file
```

**Note** that in this case it can also match a single `#`

If there should be a word character following, you can use a capture group and match at least a single word character.

```
sed -E 's/\B#([[:alnum:]_])/fruit=\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 4):

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^#[[:alpha:]]/) $i="fruit=" substr($i,2)}1' file.txt
fruit=apple sd#kf fruit=banana adfe
fruit=apple we#re fruit=banana cow
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|[[:space:]])#([[:alpha:]])/\1fruit=\2/g' file.txt
fruit=apple sd#kf fruit=banana adfe
fruit=apple we#re fruit=banana cow
```

Comment: This will replace all # in the file. 
I am trying to replace only word that starts with #

Comment: this answer generates exactly what's depicted in the question; please update the question with a more representative set of your actual data (also update the expecte doutput accordingly)

Comment: "Replace word or string that starts with # from a file" I have it in title. Updated it agin to make it better now -> Replace each occurrence of word that starts with # from a file. thank u

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(^|\s)#(\S)/\1fruit=\2/g' file
```

If a `#` is at the beginning of a line or after whitespace and is followed by non-whitespace, replace it by `fruit=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${input_data...}" | 

{m,g}awk 'sub("^ ?",_, $!(NF=NF) )' FS='(^|[ \t])[#]' OFS=' fruit='
```

_

```
fruit=apple sd#kf fruit=banana adfe
fruit=apple we#re fruit=banana cow
```

Idea is to use `FS + OFS` to handle the bulk of the situations, and only 1 `sub()` call afterwards to trim out any excess spaces created at the leading edge.

The question mark in the regex `"^ ?"` allows for rows that didn't get any replacements at all to still get printed.

No back-references needed.